# how to arrange downloaded information to fit into rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, download

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
SqlCommand Command = connection.CreateCommand();

SqlDataReader SQLRD;

Command.CommandText = "Select * from Attendance";

connection.Open();
SQLRD = Command.ExecuteReader();

string data = "";

while (SQLRD.Read())
{
    data += SQLRD[0].ToString()+  "\n";
    data += SQLRD[1].ToString() + "\n";
    data += SQLRD[2].ToString() + "\n";
    data += SQLRD[3].ToString() + "\n";
    data += SQLRD[4].ToString() + "\n";
    data += SQLRD[5].ToString() + "\n";
    data += SQLRD[6].ToString() + "\n";
    data += SQLRD[7].ToString() + "\n";
}

SQLRD.Close();
connection.Close();

string filename = @"C:\download.csv";//specified location
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename,FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
sw.WriteLine(data);
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

This is what i have done so far. currently upon clicking on download all information appear in 1 single column and is not separated into rows. I need to know how can i arrange them into rows. Also can i also know how am i to display a dialog box when the user clicks on download. Currently the file is just stored in the specified location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exporting to .csv format, you want to put commas (,) between the columns, and line returns (\n) between the rows.  Currently, you are putting a line return between every single column.  Try something like this:

```
while (SQLRD.Read())
{
     data += SQLRD[0].ToString() + ",";
                   //              ^^^ note the change from '\n' to ','
     data += SQLRD[1].ToString() + ",";
     data += SQLRD[2].ToString() + ",";
     ...
     data += SQLRD[7].ToString(); // final column doesn't need a ','
     data += "\n"; // final line separator for the entire row
}
```

Best regards,

Comment: @mellmokb if you don't mine. one last question. How can i display a download dialog box when the user clicks download.

Comment: @Mark20: Glad to help!  Note that you may run into problems if your data export to CSV ever contains commas in the actual column data values. In that case, you will need to wrap them with quotation marks, i.e., `data += "\"" + SQLRD[0].ToString() + "\",";`

Comment: thanks for that point. I will make the necessary changes. Thanks

Comment: @Mark20: RE: download dialog box.  That's a somewhat common question.  Try researching other related questions on SO or ask another question if you need more help.  You can see these links (for example) for reference.  http://syntaxhelp.com/ASP.NET/Response/download-file and http://aspalliance.com/259_downloading_files__forcing_the_file_download_dialog